# How to access a method from the main method in java?

Tags: java, arrays

I have this code:

```
public static int LastInAnArray(int[] array) {

    final int MIN_VALUE = 0;

    int lastNum = array[array.length - 1];

    if (array == null) {
        return MIN_VALUE;
    }
    else {
        return lastNum;
    }
}
```

}

In the main method I've written:

```
System.out.println(LastInAnArray(array));
```

But nothing appears.
What should I do?

Comment: Could we see your whole main method? It will help people pinpoint the problem faster

Comment: What is `array` in `main`?   What's it set to?

Comment: Why are you checking if the array is null *after* you've already attempted to access it?

Comment: You should check null before exec the value

Comment: Your code makes a belated `null` check: the code above `if (array == null)` accesses `array.length`, which triggers `NullPointerException` when `array` is `null`. I assume that this is what happens, but the error does not get displayed because you are running in an IDE.

Comment: What do you mean with "Nothing appears"? Also no error message? Can you show us how you initialize `array`?

Answer (score -6, accepted):

But it work !!!!

```
public class TEST {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] a =  {1,2,3,5,7,8,9};
    System.out.println(LastInAnArray(a));
}
public static int LastInAnArray(int[] array) {

    final int MIN_VALUE = 0;

    int lastNum = array[array.length - 1];

    if (array == null) {
        return MIN_VALUE;
    }
    else {
        return lastNum;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: This is the exact same code as in the question, right?

Comment: @MWB:  This would imply that the OP needs to clarify what it is they're struggling with, seeing or what they're passing in as an argument to this method.  We shouldn't be taking wild guesses here.

Answer (score 0):

You are first trying to extract a value from array then you are checking if the array exists! This will cause runtime error in program. Therefore you should first check the array then try to access its values.
Otherwise there is no such reason why this should not work. You may show the whole class that would help to solve the problem.